# Function expecting parameter works without one (C++)

Tags: c++, permutation

Here is the code in question. Taken from cplusplus.com. My question is how is myrandom working if in the main method nothing is being passed into it.

I thought that because of it's signature, the compiler would throw an error but not only does it not, it does exactly what I want it to, so how is this working?

Thanks a lot.

New programmer taking data structures class. Please let me know if I messed up when asking this question and how.

Ps. This is a small part of the HW. The problem set was really about search efficiency in linked lists and BSTs, which is why the permutation is necessary.

```
// random_shuffle example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::random_shuffle
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <ctime>        // std::time
#include <cstdlib>      // std::rand, std::srand

// random generator function:
int myrandom (int i) { return std::rand()%i;}

int main () {
  std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  // set some values:
  for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i); // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

  // using built-in random generator:
  std::random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end() );

  // using myrandom:
  std::random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myrandom);

  // print out content:
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest you upgrade from cplusplus.com to a better cpp reference site: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle - also, `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17 - use `std::shuffle` instead.

Comment: @Vanna thanks, that makes more sense

Comment: @JesperJuhl will do

Answer (score 3):

In cppreference you can see a possible inplementation of [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), and there you will see how it works:

```
template<class RandomIt, class RandomFunc>
void random_shuffle(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, RandomFunc&& r)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type i, n;
    n = last - first;
    for (i = n-1; i > 0; --i) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(first[i], first[r(i+1)]);
    }
}
```

In your line:

```
std::random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myrandom);
```

you are not calling `myrandom`, you're just passing the function as a parameter. Then, that parameter will be used to call the function with some parameter as you see in this line of the possible implementation:

```
swap(first[i], first[r(i+1)]);
```

`r` is the variable which holds your `myrandom` function.